# Significant digits and multiplication

Tags: statistics

My textbook (chemistry principles and practice) says:

> A more exact rule on multiplication is that the result should have about the same relative error - for example, expressed as parts per hundred (percent) or parts per thousant - as the least known quantity. For example, 99.9 * 1.008 = 101.7, not 101.

Does that mean we should aim for the same decimal point of the number with the least significant digits?
Here's an example. When I put to my calculator 104.63 * 3.4, it shows 355.742. Should I write it as 104.63 * 3.4 = 355.7 (because we're aiming to same accuracy as the 4 in the tenth place of 3.4) or maybe 104.63 * 3.4 = 360, because it should have only two significant digits?